# Процедура mysql

Tags: mysql, процедуры

первый раз пишу процедуру в mysql пожалуйста поправьте меня

```
DELIMITER // 
CREATE PROCEDURE `proc_IN` (IN var1 INT) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE a INT;
    DECLARE TimeN TEXT;
    SET a = SELECT COUNT(old_idPersonalClothing) FROM PersonalClothing WHERE old_idPersonalClothing = var1;
    IF a = 1 THEN
        SET TimeN = Select `TimeN` from Clothing, PersonalCLothing WHERE `idClothing`=`idClothing1` and `IdPersonal` = var1;
        UPDATE PersonalClothing SET Fact=Fact+1 WHERE IdPersonal = var1;
        UPDATE PersonalClothing SET dateNext= SELECT INTERVAL TimeN MONTH + `date1` FROM `PersonalClothing` WHERE `IdPersonal` = var1;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO `PersonalClothing`( `Old_IdPersonal`, `IdWorker1`, `IdClothing1`, `quantity`, `comment`, `date1`, `dateNext`, `purchasePrice`, `causeOfDelay`, `dateCause`, `transferCause`) VALUES (SELECT `Old_IdPersonal`, `IdWorker1`, `IdClothing1`, `quantity`, `comment`, `date1`, `dateNext`, `purchasePrice`, `causeOfDelay`, `dateCause`, `transferCause` FROM PersonalClothing WHERE IdPersonal` = var1;);
END IF;
END//
```

Comment: Поправить что и почему?

Comment: Ошибки которые есть в синтаксисе

Comment: Лишняя точка с запятой недалеко от последнего WHERE, например?

Comment: НУ что то вроде этого, только где то может я не правильно переменным присваиваю значение и т.д.

Comment: Очень трудно ответить про переменные, потому что вы не рассказали, что у вас за таблицы и чем этот код вообще занимается

Comment: Вы и с синтаксисом вообще - и то не дружите. Это же надо было придумать - `INSERT ... VALUES (SELECT ...)`!!! Освойте синтаксис простейших запросов сначала, не лезьте пока в процедуры.